# Linq: Finding values within a range

Tags: linq, range

I would like to match 1 Linq query with another one, based on a range provided.

For example, find all students with surnames between 'sa' and 'sn'.  I'm looking to then find students with surnames Smith and Sammy, but not Swann and Anderson.

```
var allStudents = from s in Students select s;
var boundary = from b in boundaries select new { LowEnd = b.start, HighEnd = b.end }; //LowEnd = "sa" and HighEnd = "sn"

var matches = from s in allStudents
              select new
              {
                  s.Surname > boundary.LowEnd && s.Surname <= boundary.HighEnd
                  //This will obviously give a compile error, but not sure how to do it.
               };
```

Comment: You only have one LINQ query - `boundary` is just a condition and there is no reason to use LINQ for that (unless you could have multiple pairs of boundaries). Just do `var boundary = new { LowEnd = b.start, HighEnd = b.end };` or better, still, just use `b.start` and `b.end` directly - you don't need `boundary`. Also, unless you are chaining queries, `allStudents` is not needed - just use `Students`. Your query does nothing except set the type of `allStudents`.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Linq to Objects

Comment: What is `boundaries`? What is `Students`? C# is a language of strong typing, providing types is critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using LINQ to Objects, and assuming `boundaries` is a `List<T>` of conditions any one of which needs to be matched, you can test each student object from `Students` against each boundary:

```
var matches = from s in Students
              where boundaries.Any(b => b.start.CompareTo(s.Surname) <= 0 && s.Surname.CompareTo(b.end) <= 0)
              select s;
```

NOTE: Unfortunately C# doesn't have relational string operators and extensions anywhere isn't done, so you must use the `CompareTo` method.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.